# How to receive a POST request in your org?

Tags: apex, visualforce, httprequest

I need to create lead records when a non-salesforce piece of software sends a POST request with data to my org. How is it done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple steps involved for REST in salesforce.

1. Create a Connected App from create apps option in salesforce.
2. With this App you will have Client Id, secret key , user Name and Password for Oauth Authentication for token.
3. Create an Apex class to authenticate for token initially using :

   https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
4. You can build a REST URL in salesforce using @RestResource in apex. This URL can be used by any third party applications to POST JSON formatted data.

URL for Application is :  https://yourinstance.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/LeadCreation

Here is a sample REST URL build using apex:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/LeadCreation/*')
global with sharing class RESTLeadController {

@HttpPost  
  global static String createNewLead(String leadName, String leadNumber) {
     System.debug('Lead Name: '+leadName);
     System.debug('Lead Number: '+leadNumber);
     try
     {
         Lead ld = new Lead();
         ld.Name = leadName;
         ld.lead_Number__c = leadNumber;
         insert ld;
         return 'Lead has been inserted succesfully: '+ld.Id;
     }
     catch(DMLException de)
     {
        return de.getDmlMessage(0);
     }

     return null;
  }
}
```

Follow this blogs:

http://salesforcekings.blogspot.com/2015/12/how-to-test-restful-web-services-in.html

http://www.oyecode.com/2014/08/start-building-your-own-rest-api-in.html

Comment: the frustrating thing is trying to figure out how to to authenticate for token from the third party side...

Comment: if you don't want to authenticate just create a site and have this apex class over there and do a POST to that site URL and it may work.(just a guess)

Comment: @Tyler Zika hopefully this can help you? I first use Postman to authenticate. Once you have it in Postman, it's easier to transfer that to your app. I created 2 blog posts for this: http://blog.mkorman.uk/using-postman-to-explore-salesforce-restful-web-services/ and also http://blog.mkorman.uk/integrating-net-and-salesforce-part-1-rest-api/ (which may be helpful if the external app is in C#)

Answer (score -1):

One way to achieve is this to create a VF which will handle the functionality you want to implement, on the data received by the POST functionality  and expose this VF using  QUICK ACTION/GLOBAL ACTION.

**Controller**

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/POSTHandler') 
global class POSTHandler { 
    pubilc POSTHandler(){} 
    @HttpPost global static Void HandleInput(String Value) {
         // Code Statement to process the JSON input. 
         system.debug(Value); 
    } 
}
```

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page action="HandleInput" controller="POSTHandler" />
```

Associate this VF to a Global Action and call this Setup using the URL

<-SFDC_ORG_URL->/services/data/v28.0/quickActions/POSTHandle

Comment: Can I get a code example? I can't seem to find an example anywhere.

Comment: **Controller**

 @RestResource(urlMapping='/POSTHandler')
 global class POSTHandler {
 
 pubilc POSTHandler(){}
 
 @HttpPost  
   global static Void HandleInput(String Value) {
   
   // Code Statement to process the JSON input.
   system.debug(Value);
  
   }
 }

**VF Page**

 <apex:page action="HandleInput" controller="POSTHandler" />

Associate this VF to a **Global Action**



and call this Setup using the URL
<SFDC_ORG_URL>/services/data/v28.0/quickActions/POSTHandler
<br/>
Sorry new to SE, cant edit the code. 
ps: Code is not tested. it is a vague idea.

Comment: @blackwind I don't think this is suitable for the part of the question that states that data is coming from a third party system (i.e. not from within the Salesforce UI). Also, code snippets in comments is near impossible to read. This is one of the things that you should **[edit your post](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/142121/edit)** to include.

Comment: Hi @DerekF,  thanks for the tip, i have updated the code. Also i have used the above method to send the data from 3rd party application to the sales force org.

Comment: @blackwind the vf page in your example is called POSTHandle? Is the quickActions, in the url example, the same quick actions used in SF1?

Comment: @TylerZika, yes kinda sames i guess. I used this to send data from python app to update the salesforce data via REST protocol.